# Account creation via Form authentication ASP.NET MVC page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008, forms-authentication

I'm working on an intranet, so far I have switched from Windows authentication to **Form authentication** and I'm able to connect / register etc.

But here's what I'm expected to do : Instead of being able to create and account through the usual forms route, I wish to **link the list of employees** (that has *many parameters*, such as Login, Password, Name etc.) and be able to **create a new user when I create a new Employee.**

Here is my Employee creation controller :

```
public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.CompanyList = _service.ListCompany();
        ViewBag.SupervisorList = _service.ListSupervisor();

        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Employee/Create

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Exclude = "Id")] Employee objEmployee, FormCollection form)
    {            
        ViewBag.CompanyList = _service.ListCompany();
        ViewBag.SupervisorList = _service.ListSupervisor();

        objEmployee.CreatedDate = System.DateTime.Now;
        objEmployee.UpdatedDate = System.DateTime.Now;
        objEmployee.CompanyId = int.Parse(form["CompanyId"]);
        objEmployee.Supervisor = form["Supervisor"];

        if (_service.Create(objEmployee))
            return new RedirectResult(Url.Action("Index"));

        else
        {
            if (!_service.Validate(objEmployee))
                return View();
            else
                return new RedirectResult(Url.Action("Index", "Error", new { Message = "Error Create Employee", NextPage = CRAWebSiteMVC.Properties.Resources.Employee + @"/" + CRAWebSiteMVC.Properties.Resources.Create }));
        } 
    }
```

And here's the *usual* way I create an account via the normal form auth. registering :

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Attempt to register the user
            try
            {
                WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password);
                WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            [...]
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

**How may I create an account via the Employee creation panel and basically replace the usual user list by the employee list?**

Comment: do You mean to create an Email Model and at the same time. Add it into the UserStore and UserManager Class?

I hope you know that you can use the UserStore and UserManager class to create the "Usual user" that you were talking about.

Comment: Being new to the technology, I didn't. I'll look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now Usually the context, is automatically declared as db <- in the controllers.
it is Declared as

```
private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
```

But in this Case in my example it says. `context` so just Change `context` to `db` if ApplicationDbContext is declared.

The bottom is an Example of Creating a User class and an Employee class at the same time. So inserting a record to the User While having a reference to the Employee class. But I guess you get that by now.

Notice that, I didn't add an encryption to the password. Cause that is a whole new topic of question.

```
var userStore = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context);
        var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(userStore);



        if (!context.Users.Any(t => t.UserName == "admin@Konek.com"))
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = "admin@Konek.com", Email = "admin@Konek.com" };
            userManager.Create(user, "Password1!");

            context.Roles.AddOrUpdate(r => r.Name, new IdentityRole { Name = "Admin" });
            context.Roles.AddOrUpdate(r => r.Name, new IdentityRole { Name = "Receptionist" });
            context.Roles.AddOrUpdate(r => r.Name, new IdentityRole { Name = "Security" });
            context.SaveChanges();

            userManager.AddToRole(user.Id, "Admin");

            Employee admingEmployee = new Employee
            {
                Age=25,
                Citizenship="Filipino",
                CivilStatus=CivilStatus.Single,
                DateOfBirth=DateTime.Now,
                EmailAddress="admin@Konek.com",
                FirstName="Admin",
                Gender=Gender.Male,
                HomeAddress="None",
                LandLine="531-5555",
                LastName="Administrator",
                MiddleName="admin",
                MobileNumber="09275225222",
                Photo = "*******",
                PlaceofBirth="*****",
                Password = "********",
                Role=Role.Admin
            };

            context.Employees.Add(admingEmployee);
            context.SaveChanges();
```